# Why does Interval.contains(Interval) need to include other.start < this.end condition?

Tags: algorithm, jodatime, intervals

In Joda-Time, the implementation for [`Interval.contains(Interval)`](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/bd79f1c4245e79b3c2c56d7b04fde2a6e191fa42/src/main/java/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInterval.java#L186) looks like this:

```
return (thisStart <= otherStart && otherStart < thisEnd && otherEnd <= thisEnd);
```

I'm having trouble understanding why the second part, `otherStart < thisEnd` is needed, i. e. why wouldn't

```
thisStart <= otherStart && otherEnd <= thisEnd
```

suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a particular case explained in the comments, to avoid a `other` interval that has 0 duration (start == end) to be located at the `thisEnd`

`thisStart` time is included, `thisEnd` time is excluded

> [09:00 to 10:00) contains [10:00 to 10:00)  = false (otherStart equals thisEnd)

```
    this                 --+
|----------|               +--- not contained
           | <-- other   --+

    this                 --+
|----------|               +--- contained
        |    <-- other   --+


    this                 --+
|----------|               +--- contained
|            <-- other   --+
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of points in time, where the start equals the end.

```
[00:00 -> 00:10) does     contain [00:00 -> 00:00)

[00:00 -> 00:10) does not contain [00:10 -> 00:10)
```